# Best approach to handle asynchronous data using Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I need to fetch data from an API and show it in the UI (textfields) after the `onPressed` of a button is called.

Here is my API call:

```
class CepService {

  final String cep;

  CepService(this.cep);

  Future<ResultCep> fetchCep() async {
    Dio dio = Dio();

    try {
      final response = await dio.get('https://viacep.com.br/ws/$cep/json/');
      print(response.data);
      return ResultCep.fromJson(response.data);

    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Requisição inválida!');    }
    }
  }
```

And here is my FutureProvider so I can read the value in the UI:

```
final getCepProvider = FutureProvider.family<ResultCep, String>((ref, String cep) async {
  final service = CepService(cep);
  final finalCep =  await service.fetchCep();
  return finalCep;
});

final cepStateProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => '');
```

The issue is how I connect the `FutureProvider` and the UI and handle the asynchronous values inside it.
For instance, here is part of my UI code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final cep = ref.watch(cepStateProvider);
    final cepResult = ref.watch(getCepProvider(cep));

    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
           child:Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    buildCustomTextField(
                        controller: _cepController,
                        labelText: 'CEP',
                        maxWidth: 250,
                        validator: (value) {}),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          ref.read(cepStateProvider.notifier).state = _cepController.text;
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: const Size(100, 50),
                            backgroundColor: colorPrimary,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            )),
                        child: const Text("Buscar"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                buildCustomTextField(
                    controller: _addressController,
                    labelText: 'Endereço',
                    maxWidth: 400,
                    validator: (value) {}),
```

I have other `TextFields` that I need to fill besides the `_address` one, and the idea is to allow the user to type in a CEP and click on the 'Buscar' button to fill in automatically, or allow the user to type in manually.

What is the best (and simple, if possible) approach here? Should I wrap everything inside something like `cepResult.when()`? Or would it be better to use `NotifierProvider`? If so, could you share a similar example?